# 2393 MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR After migrating from amqmdnet.dll to amqmdnetstd.dll

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq

I am attempting to update my IBM MQ application running on .NET from the amqmdnet.dll to the amqmdnetstd.dll from the nuget package "IBMMQDotnetClient". After making the update, I receive the following Exception when attempting to 'new' the MQQueueManager :

```
Exception thrown: 'IBM.WMQ.MQException' in amqmdnetstd.dll: 'MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR'
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.Connect(String queueManagerName)
   at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable properties)
```

My code is essentially identical to the .NET sample code given by IBM for a managed client.

My amqmdnet.dll was version 9.0.0.2 and I'm attempting to migrate to amqmdnetstd.dll v9.3.3. I'm running the application on Windows.

In the Trace log I see the following error:

```
000001C1 17:27:55.575445   145264.43   SSL Server Certificate validation failed - RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
000001C2 17:27:55.575464   145264.43  ------------}  MQEncryptedSocket.ClientValidatingServerCertificate(Object,X509Certificate,X509Chain,SslPolicyErrors) rc=OK
000001C3 17:27:55.579448   145264.43   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
```

I'm using the same cipher as before - TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256. As far as I can tell, this is still a valid CipherSpec.

I am wondering if anyone is aware of some breaking change between the IBMMQDotnetClient versions that would be causing an SSL Issue like this? I read through the changes between each version and was unable to find anything.

I've tried different CipherSpecs, including TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 and just using ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER. I've double checked the label on the cert matches the label that my application is looking for.

Comment: What type of key store do you have for cert stored in?

Comment: @JoshMc I have SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY set to "*SYSTEM", is that what you mean? I'm not super familiar with certificates and how they work.

Comment: I don't see any indication that it is about the cipher. I understand the error message like there is an issue with the remote certificate ( = the queue manager's certificate) and the validatation of it was not successful on your site. Maybe you can analyse in this direction? What CA has sigend the Qmgr's certificate and is that CA a trusted CA in your trust store?

Comment: @NineFriends verified the certificate is trusted in my trust store. I wouldn't expect any issue with the certificates since the application worked prior to updating the .dll.

Comment: Where you using manged mode (windows key store) before the update?   Can you provide more of the trace file from above those three lines?

Comment: Are you running both on the same server.

Comment: @JoshMc yes to both your questions. I was using managed mode previously, and I'm running the updated one on the same server (though I plan on running it on a new server eventually, doing the same one now to reduce the number of variables). Are there specific lines from the trace file I can send you? I'm concerned about posting sensitive data here, seems time consuming to take any sensitive data out.

Comment: How many lines have 145264.43? Can you try 9.2.0.11 and see if it makes any difference

Comment: @JoshMc I see 474 lines with 145264.43. I tried version 9.2.0.11, the trace looks the same unfortunately. I get a different error message thrown in my application, because in 9.3.3 IBM updated the error messages in the dotnet client, so this is expected. Error message in 9.2.0.11 is `2538 MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE`. Error message in my AMQERR01.LOG file is `AMQ9202E: Remote host not available, retry later.` if that's helpful. Thanks

Comment: I'm digging into how my server is configured some more, I just noticed that there is an IBM MQ installation on the machine already - version 8.0.0.8. Would this affect anything if I'm using the "standalone" .dll now? And are there additional steps I need to take if I'm going from using an installed version to standalone version? I'm a bit fuzzy on how the application uses the MQ installation versus the .dll.

Comment: Just an update, I uninstalled the IBM WebSphere MQ installation from the machine. Was getting a weird error with the 9.3.3 version of the .dll so downgraded to 9.3.2.1 and I'm seeing the same error now in my trace `The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve the issue, we didn't have the root and intermediate certificates from the server installed in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" folder in windows. This begs the question how it worked previously without the certificates, I'm thinking MQ was previously looking in a different location for certificates and after updating it was no longer looking in this location.

Comment: Good job finding the cause.   One difference is the older version used .NET framework and the newer version uses either .net core or .net 6.  Maybe the underlying windows SSL provider has changed or is more strict or they call it in a different way which makes it more strict?

Comment: You said 4 days earlier you had already checked that (in response to my comment).

Comment: @NineFriends you're right, you did tell me to check it. I had the certificate installed and assumed it couldn't be an issue since it worked before updating the version. However, I needed to install the root/intermediate certificates in the folder "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" instead of the personal folder where I initially tried installing them. I appreciate the lead, you did cause me to go back and check it.